# Вывод списка, заданного vector в MDI приложении MFC

Tags: mfc, c++

Я написала класс для задания списка студентов:

```
class students
{
    protected:
    char* student; //студент
    int ects; //балл ECTS
    int propusk; //количество пропусков

public:
    students(char* stud, int ec, int prop);
    ~students(void);
    list<students> m_list;
    friend ostream & operator << (ostream & out, students &m_list)
    {
        out << m_list.student << " ";
        out << m_list.ects << endl;
        out << m_list.propusk << endl;
        return out;
    }
};
```

пыталась вызвать его в

```
BOOL CMDI_3Doc::OnNewDocument()
{
    if (!CDocument::OnNewDocument())
        return FALSE;
    m_list.push_back(students("аи", 100, 5));
    for ( Iter = m_list.begin( ) ; Iter != m_list.end( ) ; Iter++ )
        cout << *Iter <<  " " << endl;

    // TODO: add reinitialization code here
    // (SDI documents will reuse this document)

    return TRUE;
}
```

но ничего не происходит.
Что мне добавить или изменить, чтобы поместить список студентов в документ?

Comment: Что возвращает функция OnNewDocument()?

Comment: Точно, в этом проблема, а куда тогда код писать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сперва вопрос: вы уверены, что метод OnNewDocument() вообще выполняется? Выдели его работу в отладчике? У меня есть сильные подозрения, что "нет". Но если "да", то давайте посмотрим далее.

В дизайне класса есть несколько ошибок:

1. Переменная m_list объявлена как член класса students, хотя сам класс описывает одного студента. Следовательно, каждый экземпляр этого класса будет иметь в себе список студентов (пустой или кем-то чем-то заполненный???) - это явно нелогично: элементы и контейнер этих элементов не должны быть одной сущность.
2. char* student куда лучше перевести на std::string student. Это все-таки C++ как-никак...
3. Отсутствует конструктор копирования (вернее, используется сгенерированный компилятором по-умолчанию), в то время как он явно необходим:

   ```
   m_list.push_back(students("аи", 100, 5));
   ```